# Transfer Data from a Master Worksheet to Multiple based on Column using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have seen a couple of post about this issue and I am still struggling. I am new to VBA but loving it. My Problem is this 
I have a Excel sheet 32,000 + rows. Its a healthcare provider network. 32,000 healthcare providers over 200+ countries. What i would like to do is. Have the Macro find each country in Sheet 1 and then create and name a new sheet and populate this new sheet with only data for this country. So it would first find Afghanistan, populate sheet 2 with the Information in Sheet one about Afghanistan and then create a new sheet call it Albania and populate sheet 3 with Albania and so on until Zimbabwe

Here is the Code i have so far

```
Sub RoundedRectangle2_Click()
```

`Dim lastrow, erow As Long`

```
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
If Sheet1.Cells(i, 7) = "Ireland" Then
Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Copy

erow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count,
1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 1)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 2)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Cop
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 3)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 4)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 5)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 6)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 7).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 7)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 8).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 8)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 9)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 10)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 11).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 11)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 12).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 12)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 13).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 13)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 14).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 14)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 15).Copy
Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 15)
End If
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Columns().AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

ANY HELP WILL BE GREATLY APPRECIATED

Comment: You need to provide us with more information.

Could you send a example of few lines of the excelfile?

Comment: Are all of the countries really longhand? Why not something like three letter ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 standard country codes?

Comment: Hi all here are my column headings: Id Salutation, First Name Name Line1 Line2 Line3 City Post Code Country Provider Type Phone1 Tg 1st Status Tg 2nd Status Tg 3rd Status Email Web Site. It is just basic contact info. and it goes on for 32,000 + lines. Country is in the 10th column this is the column that will decided when a new sheet should be created and information brought to that sheet. THANK YOU FOR THE HELP GUYS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked Scott Holtzman filtering technique using 'Autofilter' method

And since you're dealing whith a lot of rows, I thought it could be of some help to test an alternative one

That's why, along with some "cosmetics" on Scott's code, you may want to try the following code

```
Option Explicit

Sub RoundedRectangle2_Click()
Dim lastRow
Dim baseSheet As Worksheet, newSht As Worksheet
Dim searchedRng As Range, dataRng As Range, headerRng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim processedCountries As String, country As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set baseSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' this is the sheet where all data resides
With baseSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    Set searchedRng = .Range("J2:J" & lastRow)
    Set dataRng = .Range("A1:Q" & lastRow)
    Set headerRng = .Range("A1:Q1")

    For Each cell In searchedRng
        country = cell.Value
        If InStr(processedCountries, "-" & country & "-") = 0 Then ' check if the country has already been processd

            ' set the 'Country' sheet
            Set newSht = setNewSheet(ThisWorkbook, country, headerRng)

            ' filter and copy values to the 'Country' sheet
'            Call FilterAndCopy(dataRng, country, newSht) ' option 1
            Call FilterAndCopy2(headerRng, searchedRng, dataRng, country, newSht) ' option 2

            processedCountries = processedCountries & "-" & country & "-" ' update processed countries string

        End If
    Next cell
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub FilterAndCopy(rangeToFilter As Range, filterValue As String, sheetToPasteTo As Worksheet)

With rangeToFilter
    .AutoFilter 10, filterValue
    .Offset(1).Resize(rangeToFilter.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy sheetToPasteTo.Range("A2") 'copy data for filterValue under header
    .AutoFilter
End With
sheetToPasteTo.Columns().AutoFit

End Sub

Sub FilterAndCopy2(headerRng As Range, searchedRng As Range, rangeToFilter As Range, filterValue As String, sheetToPasteTo As Worksheet)
Dim cell As Range
Dim rangeToCopy As Range

Set rangeToCopy = headerRng
For Each cell In searchedRng
    If cell.Value = filterValue Then Set rangeToCopy = Union(rangeToCopy, rangeToFilter.Offset(cell.row - 1).Resize(1))
Next cell
rangeToCopy.Copy sheetToPasteTo.Range("A1") 'copy data for filterValue under header
sheetToPasteTo.Columns().AutoFit

End Sub


Function setNewSheet(myWorkBook As Workbook, shtName As String, Optional headerRng As Variant) As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set setNewSheet = myWorkBook.Worksheets(shtName)
On Error GoTo 0

If setNewSheet Is Nothing Then
    myWorkBook.Worksheets.Add

    Set setNewSheet = ActiveSheet
    setNewSheet.Name = shtName
Else
    setNewSheet.Cells.ClearContents
End If

If Not IsMissing(headerRng) Then headerRng.Copy setNewSheet.Range("A1")

End Function
```

where you can try and test both Scott's filtering technique (option 1 -> uncomment the "FilterAndCopy" sub call and comment the "FilterAndCopy2" one) and mine (do the opposite!)

Comment: UNBELIEVABLE!! This has worked so well. It is doing everything i need. thank you so much for your time and assistance. Much respect from Dublin.

Comment: glad to know. also curious about which option proves faster. did you try both?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.AutoFilter` method will come in handy.

Place the unique country list is on a worksheet called `CountryList` in cells A1:A201 and try the below code. I surmised your actual range references from the code in your question, but adjust if needed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filter()

Dim wsCL As Worksheet
Set wsCL = Worksheets("CountryList")

Dim rCL As Range, rCountry As Range
Set rCL = wsCL.Range("A1:A201")

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each rCountry In rCL

    'check if country exists
    Dim rTest As Range
    Set rTest = ws1.Range("J1:J" & lRow).Find(rCountry.Value2, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not rTest Is Nothing Then 'if country is found create sheet and copy data

        Dim wsNew As Worksheet
        Worksheets.Add (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        Set wsNew = ActiveSheet
        wsNew.Name = rCountry.Value2
        ws1.Range("A1:Q1").Copy wsNew.Range("A1") 'place header row

        With ws1.Range("A1:Q" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter 10, rCountry.Value2
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsNew.Range("B1") 'copy data for country under header
            .AutoFilter
        End With

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Scott, Thank you for the help. Unfortunately I am getting a Run-time error 91 at rCL = wsCL.Range("A1:A201") My entire CountryList excel sheet is ("A1:Q32173") the country column is ("J1:J32173) I hope this helps.

Comment: @PhilipConnell - Error is fixed. See edited code. Make sure to follow the first point in my answer about creating the unique country list.

Comment: Thank you again for your help ran the edited code getting Compile error: Variable Not Defined: the ws is highlighted blue on the line Set rTest = ws.Range("J1:J" & lRow).Find(rCountry.Value2, lookat:=xlWhole). I changed it to ws1.Range and this seemed to work. WAS THIS CORRECT TO DO ? same for ws.Range("A1:Q1").Copy wsNew.Range("A1") Once i edited this part i got Run-Time Error 99 Script our of Range. Again thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: @PhilipConnell - yes, they should read `ws1` as that is the variable name (not `ws` ... apologies for not compiling on my end). What line did you get the last error on?

Comment: No need for apologies you are a great help. There is nothing highlighted on the Debug nothing in blue nothing in yellow. It just says Run-Time Error Script out of range

Comment: @PhilipConnell Cpde compiles for me. Can you try running from scratch again and make sure you didn't accidentally delete a letter or move something by accident.

Comment: User3598756 cosmetics worked really well. Thank you for your help on the matter. I am new to this website. Is there a way I can still give you Reputation points? I would like to as your code really helped

Comment: @PhilipConnell - glad you got a solution. You can upvote the answer - by ticking the grey up arrow on the top left